# Alertmanager Match vs Match_re

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

```
match:
  [ <labelname>: <labelvalue>, ... ]

# A set of regex-matchers an alert has to fulfill to match the node.
match_re:
  [ <labelname>: <regex>, ... ]
```

My question is what is the difference between a match and a match_re statement?
I have used both of the within prometheus and the effect they have is the same.

Any help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 9):

With "match_re" you can use regular expression like in the following examples:

```
service: "mysql|postgre"

system: ".*_(foo|boo)$"

recipient: "(.*,)?customer/sms(,.*)?"

alertname: "watchdog.*alert"
```

Comment: can we use both `match` and `match_re` for a receiver?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.

Answer (score 7):

From the `v0.22.2` both `match` and `match_re` are deprecated in favor of `matchers`. A nice new feature is the possibility to define [negative matchers](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/commit/0548bb1f3c65e87d0ce663d436bc8f71fb621e42).

```
# DEPRECATED: Use matchers below.
# A set of equality matchers an alert has to fulfill to match the node.
match:
  [ <labelname>: <labelvalue>, ... ]

# DEPRECATED: Use matchers below.
# A set of regex-matchers an alert has to fulfill to match the node.
match_re:
  [ <labelname>: <regex>, ... ]
  
# A list of matchers that an alert has to fulfill to match the node. 
matchers:
  [ - <matcher> ... ]
```

[Source](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/e3fb99cc2d24330fdb81aa1d466c19b3de328b5b/docs/configuration.md#route)

Answer (score 5):

Use `matchers` instead of them:

```
  routes:
  - receiver: 'database-pager'
    group_wait: 10s
    matchers:
    - service=~"mysql|cassandra"
  - receiver: 'frontend-pager'
    group_by: [product, environment]
    matchers:
    - team="frontend"
```

In newer versions `match` and `match_re` are deprecated in favor of matchers.

Comment: `matchers` was introduced in v 0.22. If the reader is using something older than that, they'll still need to use `match` & `match_re`.